# Position floating action buttons next to eachother horizontally

Tags: android, xml, floating-action-button

I currently have 2 floating action buttons that look like this...

[image]

I want a small space between the buttons but I can't seem to achieve this...

xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#7c7c7c"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relContainer"
            android:background="@drawable/bordershadow2"
            android:paddingBottom="17dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bordershadow"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/purchaseTableLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1,2">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="@string/purchaseText"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/title_size"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/purchaseTableLayout"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'() "
                android:hint="Search"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/searchEditText"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1,2">

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="3.0">

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/sortRaceSpinner"
                        style="@style/SortSpinner"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:entries="@array/sort_race_array"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/title_size" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/sortAffinitySpinner"
                        style="@style/SortSpinner"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:entries="@array/sort_affinity_array"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/title_size" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/sortSpinner"
                        style="@style/SortSpinner"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:entries="@array/sort_array"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/title_size" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_payment" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
        app:backgroundTint="#F44336"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/fab"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I'm not sure but it may have to do with the RelativeLayouts I'm using.

**EDIT**

Preview looks good

[image]

However it's still out of place on my phone...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move them inside `LinearLayout`

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                 android:id="@+id/fabPayment"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                 android:src="@drawable/ic_payment" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                 android:id="@+id/fabInfo"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:src="@drawable/ic_info_outline"
                 app:backgroundTint="#F44336" />  

       </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have added the entire xml @vasilis

Comment: I have run into another issue now. The buttons on the preview display differently than my phone. I will edit my post. @vasilis

Comment: what do you mean it's out of place? it's the same with emulator's output...if you mean the distance is too big, you can replace on the fabPayment the margin to value lower than 10

Comment: if you want the buttons closer to the edge, you can change the margin to the LineanLayout. The fab_margin is 16dp, you can make it as much as you want